# How to make combobox read-only, or at least recognize when a typed value is in the combobox list

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I made a dialog box (handle is hConfigDialog) in the Resource View, that has a combobox (IDC_COMBO1). The combobox has a defined set of values, lets say 1, 2, 3.

I understand if I type in 4 into the combobox, and use the following code

```
int index = SendDlgItemMessage(hConfigDialog, IDC_COMBO1, 
                               CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
```

index will be -1, since 4 is not in the defined list.

But instead, if I type in 3, I still get index -1. However, if I click 3 from the drop down box, I will get index 3.

I have been looking at the properties listed for the combobox, and it seems like there is no option to set it to read only. Is this true? Is there at least a way to get it to recognize that the typed in 3 is actually a value in the drop down box, so I will get index 3?

Maybe instead of getting the index, I should just read the value in the combobox, so I will know the value regardless of the index it thinks its at...but I just wanted to confirm there is no way to get around this index issue.

Comment: If you want to restrict the user to the items in the list, use the drop down list style, `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`

Comment: Thank you David, thats what I was looking for